# Show confirmation dialog in Fancybox when submitting form with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

I am trying  to control a form submit confirmation using a Fancybox confirmation message.

How can I add an event to the form submit using jQuery fancybox?

my form source is bellow:

```
<form name="oactivite" action="url" method="POST" onsubmit="return confirmTask(' do you confirm task : '+document.forms['oactivite'].elements['task_id'].options[this.document.forms['oactivite'].elements['task_id'].selectedIndex].text+'?');">
    <select name="task_id" id="task_id">
        <option value="1">Pause</option>
        <option value="2">Digit</option>
        <option value="3">editing</option>
    </select>
    <div name="emp_id" value="20" style="display:none" />
    <input type="submit" value="validate task"/>
  </form>
```

how can i show a fancybox confirm message when i call confirmTask ?

Comment: Look at [this example](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation) , it is a modal confirmation dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should show us some of your code, but hopefully this helps. Fancy box has a method to open the lightbox, you can call that on the form submit like so:

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
    $("#myfancybox").trigger('click');
    return false; // prevents form from submitting
});
```

You can then put another element (for example, your confirm button) which then calls the form submit:

```
$('#confirmbutton').click(function() {
    $('#myform').submit();
});
```

See the [tips and tricks section on fancy box](http://fancybox.net/blog) for reference